# Saving image/file through django shell

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload, django-shell, python

I am trying to save an image file through django shell.

My `model.py` is:

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pic = models.ImageField()
```

Everything is fine with admin and forms but I want to save image using shell:

something like

```
>>> user1 = User(name='abc', pic="what to write here")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232434/upload-a-file-from-django-shell

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
from django.core.files import File

user1=User(name='abc')
user1.pic.save('abc.png', File(open('/tmp/pic.png', 'r')))
```

You will end up with the image `abc.png` copied into the `upload_to` directory
specified in the `ImageField`.

In this case, the `user1.pic.save` method will also save the `user1` instance.
The documentation for saving an `ImageField` can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/

Comment: I used this method trying to save a png, and got this error: `codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
odeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 207: char
 to <undefined>`  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @AllTradesJack use 'rb' instead of 'r' flag, as Roy answered below

Answer (score 35):

```
from django.core.files import File
user1=User(name='abc')
user1.pic.save('abc.png', File(open('/tmp/pic.png', 'rb')))
```

Please Use 'rb' instead of 'r'. If you are using python3.

Comment: This should be a comment on the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile
user1=User(name='abc')
user1.pic.save('abc.png', UploadedFile(file=open('/tmp/pic.png', 'rb'), content_type='image/png'))
```