# How do I add image to object in Python?

Tags: django

Seemingly trivial question, but I'm stuck.

I'm trying to add add a photo to a model's `ImageField` when I create the model.  But I don't know how to specify the photo.  Do I specify the path, or a photo object?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()

# I tried these, none works
from PIL import Image
MyModel.objects.create(img='img.jpg')
MyModel.objects.create(img=Image.open('img.jpg'))
MyModel.objects.create(img=open('img.jpg', 'r'))
MyModel.objects.create(img=open('img.jpg', 'w'))
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332086/saving-image-file-through-django-shell)

Comment: @JordanM. That post solved my problem, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving image/file through django shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332086/saving-image-file-through-django-shell)